# Pass positional arguments to constructor in Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

Using Ninject 3.0, I know I can pass arguments to the concrete service's constructor at resolve time thus:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IService>.To<ConcreteService>();
MySettings mySettings = new DefaultConcreteServiceSettings();

IService service = kernel.Get<IService>(new[] { new ConstructorArgument("settings", mySettings) });
```

The `ConstructorArgument` object takes two parameters - the first is the name of the argument to override, and the second is its injected value.

Is it possible to inject the `mySettings` to `IService`'s constructor based on its position in the constructor footprint rather than the formal parameter name?

**EDIT**

Per @nemesv's request, I'm adding some sample code for `ConcreteService`. My motivation is based on a notion, that depending on the argument name for each and every concrete implementation of `IService`, makes the code fragile:

```
public class ConcreteService : IService
{
    readonly ISettings _settings;

    public ConcreteService(ISettings settings) 
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
}

public class ConcreteServiceBySomePoorGuyWhoCantSpell : IService
{
    readonly ISettings _settings;

    public ConcreteServiceBySomePoorGuyWhoCantSpell(ISettings suttingz) 
    {
        _settings = suttingz;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample `ConcreteService`? What is your problem with using the argument name? Why do you want to bind based on the position?

Comment: Why don't you register your `ISettings` in the container itself. So Ninject will be automatically resolve it for you: `kernel.Bind<ISetting>().ToConstant(mySettings);IService service = kernel.Get<IService>() });` if you don't want to use this mysetting in every Iservice you can use the `WhenInjectedInto` configuration option to restrict where to inject the default settings

Comment: @memesv - I ended up doing something approximate to what you suggested. For the sake of completion though, is it possible to inject at resolve time using positional-args?

Comment: No, positional argument injection is not supported by out of the box. However you can create your own `IConstructorArgument` implementation where you can implement the position based argument injection.

Answer (score 1):

No, you would have to get around this by using bindings as `ToProvider`, abstract factories or contextual bindings for each combination of overloads using positional parameters such as:

```
Bind<IService>().To<MyService>().WithConstructorArgument(...).Named(...)
Bind<IService>().To<MyService>().WithConstructorArgument(...).WhenInjectedInto(...)
```